# How can I make a grid element have a column for every child it has?

Tags: html, css

Considering this HMTL:

```css
/* Desired styiling: */
.container {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: 250px 250px 250px /* this is the part to automate */
   grid-template-rows: 50px;
}

.child {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="child">x</div>
   <div class="child">y</div>
   <div class="child">z</div> 
</div>
```

And the fact that the number of .child element can change.

How can I make .container have display grid and a column of size 250px for every .child el?
I know this can be done in JS but I was looking for a css solution.

Comment: grid-auto-columns:250px; grid-auto-flow:column ?

Comment: or just display : flex if it's about a single line :) (hint flex-shrink:0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your code like below:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-columns: 250px; /* size of each column */
  grid-auto-flow: column; /* column flow */
  grid-template-rows: 50px;
}

.child {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">x</div>
  <div class="child">y</div>
  <div class="child">z</div>
</div>
```